# Making an MS Excel User-Defined-Functions

Tags: c#, excel, user-defined-functions

i'm trying to create a User Defined Function for MS Excel in C#.

But no matter what I try, when I try to add the Add-in to Excel I always get the infamous "*The file you have selected does not contain a new automation server, or you do not have sufficient privileges to register the automation server*" error.

Here's the code that I took from and online example just to try it out:

```
// C#

using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace AutomationAddin
{
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
    public class MyUdf
    {
        public MyUdf()
        {
        }

        public double addMeTest(double x, double y)
        {
            return x + y;
        }

        [ComRegisterFunctionAttribute]
        public static void RegisterFunction(Type t)
        {
            Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(
                "CLSID\\{" + t.GUID.ToString().ToUpper() +
                   "}\\Programmable");
        }

        [ComUnregisterFunctionAttribute]
        public static void UnregisterFunction(Type t)
        {
            Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot.DeleteSubKey(
                "CLSID\\{" + t.GUID.ToString().ToUpper() +
                  "}\\Programmable");
        }
    }
}
```

---

I tried this with **MS Visual Studio 2012** on **Excel 2013 x64** and **Excel 2010 x86**

SolutionsI've found and tried with no success:

- [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)] as seen in the code
- [ComRegisterFunctionAttribute] AND [ComUnregisterFunctionAttribute] as seen in the code
- regasm /codebase  did nothing as well
- Turning on/off "Register COM interop" (VS running as admin when building)
- [assembly: ComVisible(true)] set to true
- Tried different code examples from the web
- Read this on stackoverflow: [How to get COM Server for Excel written in VB.NET installed and registered in Automation Servers list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506858/how-to-get-com-server-for-excel-written-in-vb-net-installed-and-registered-in-au)
- I've also tried all of the above together - no luck here
- Ran Excel in admin mode

So please guys, if you can tell me what am I missing here and maybe even tell me what should I do to make it work I would be so grateful! Thanks in advance!

I will gladly provide any additional info if needed.

P.S. Haven't had any sleep for two nights now so I might be screwing something up in a really stupid way. If someone could test this code if it works and tell me their project setup it just might help.

Comment: Long shot here, have you tried running excel in admin mode?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I did. So yes, but to no avail.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7753/Create-an-Automation-Add-In-for-Excel-using-NET seems to address your problem, hope it helps!

Comment: @JuStDaN Thanks, but the code example in my question is exactly for that very page and I've tried their solutions.

Comment: @Janisimo, do you compile your assembly for AnyCPU platform?

Comment: @user626528, should I not?

Comment: @Janisimo, I believe you should, but trying different options might help. Also, don't forget to use the version of regasm (32 or 64 bit) matching your Excel bitness.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this library https://exceldna.codeplex.com, it simplifies creation of UDFs a lot.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. I've successfully created XLL UDF's before with this tool, it's great. But the problem is that I have a university assignment and they want me to create a COM automation Add-in, that's a requirement :(