# Excel COM Add-In, with Auto-Completion and Documentation

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, excel, xaml

I have to develop "*something*" that provides functions and ribbons for Excel. For example there should be a function which connects to the internet, and returns the current temperature of a place (which is a parameter). And there should be a button in the ribbons, which shows a dialog with settings (url etc.).

I thought, the best way to accomplish this, would be an Excel-Add-In. I know that there are two ways of providing user defined functions: an XLL-Add-In, and a COM-Add-In. The XLL-Add-In has a very ugly way of defining the ribbons: I have to provide the xml as string. This is very refactoring-unfriendly. That's why I wanted to use a COM-Add-In. But I read [here](http://www.adamtibi.net/07-2012/using-c-sharp-net-user-defined-functions-udf-in-excel) that a COM-Add-In has no auto-completion of my UDFs in excel.

So I am wondering if there is a way, to easily and cleanly create ribbons in code and windows in xaml, and still have auto-completion and documentation in excel. This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998824/automation-add-in-vs-com-add-in) lets me think, that these two requirements exclude each other. Nevertheless I hope there is a way to do this.

Many thanks in advance.